# Response.Body returning an "empty" body

Tags: go

I am getting a response back as well as header responses and everything, but for some reason the body is empty:

https://repl.it/repls/HastyAggravatingArchitect

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)


const url = "http://comicbookdb.com/search.php"

func main() {
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    q := request.URL.Query()
    q.Add("form_search", "Captain America")
    q.Add("form_searchtype", "Character")
  // http://comicbookdb.com/search.php?form_search=captain%20america&form_searchtype=Character
    request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    client := http.DefaultClient
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("Date"))
    fmt.Println(response.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("Server"))
    fmt.Println(response.Body)  

    r, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

I commented in the full URL so that you can check it out yourself and see that the response body should not be empty.

Comment: I can get the response body in Python: https://repl.it/repls/FeistyMinorAccess

It must be something stupid that I'm missing in this Go code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the go program, you need provide additional header in this case it's a `Cookie` header:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

const url = "http://comicbookdb.com/search.php"

func main() {
    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    // Here is requeired header
    request.Header.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=jmujtqjctuk1bv1g02ni88q9u5'") 
    q := request.URL.Query()
    q.Add("form_search", "Captain America")
    q.Add("form_searchtype", "Character")
    request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("Date"))
    fmt.Println(response.StatusCode)
    fmt.Println(response.Header.Get("Server"))
    fmt.Println(response.Body)

    r, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

The output:

```
Mon, 09 Jul 2018 06:13:35 GMT
200
Apache
&{0xc420060040 {0 0} false <nil> 0x5e2200 0x5e2190}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org ...
..... omitted ....
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thanks so much! 

I knew it was something dumb ...

So does Python's requests library automatically include the cookie header? https://repl.it/repls/FeistyMinorAccess

Comment: I dont know about `python`, all I know what with `go` you must be literal.

Comment: How did you generate the cookie? Did you just copy and paste from your browser?

Comment: First time, I've used chrome developer console, there is an option `copy as cURL command`. You can pass any arbitrary string, I've used `PHPSESSID=XXXXXXXX` and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is something related to the page. You can get away with setting an additional header. In this case, `Connection` header.

```
...
request.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
client := http.DefaultClient
response, err := client.Do(request)
...
```